# What are the Impacts on an economy when a large mining venture begins to reduce production and lay off workers in a remote region?

Tags: macroeconomics, microeconomics

I am currently unsure about how such a question above should be answered. To clarify , I am confused as  of which topics relating to the question i should discussion in order to answer it. (For example) Fewer jobs in the region means fewer small business due to poor economic conditions which impacts the region's long term trade.

Does any with experience in the economics have an idea of how such a question is to be answered?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what they mine there and how big are the layoffs. Boomtowns are usually formed when they set up mines in remote regions. After the mines are depleted or become economically non-viable, workers leave and the boomtown becomes a ghost town. Since the economy of such places heavily relies on income from mining, it cannot survive once the money stop flowing. You can read up on the history of boomtowns and ghost towns on wikipedia to see if that is what you are looking for.

Boomtowns:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boomtown

Ghost towns:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghost_town